# My PHP Update Code is not writing to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie php programmer.  I have this actionfrm.php and when it runs i get this msg:

```
UPDATE personal 
   SET membername='test this', 
       sponsorid='102', 
       dateofjoining='2012-07-23', 
       address='13432 main', 
       city='pomona', 
       state='CA', 
       country='USA', 
       mobileno='8187321592', 
       countrycode='1', 
       dateofbirth='1988/05/03', 
       emailid='tlhkapil@gmail.com' 
 WHERE membername='test this'

update query succeeded
```

However, it is NOT writing to the database.  i took this code and put it into phpmyadmin and got this msg: 0 rows affected.

Here is the code:

```
<?php include('dbconnect.php'); ?>
<?php
$membername=$_POST['membername'];
if(isset($_POST['username']) and $_POST['username']!=""){
$sponsorid=$_SESSION['memberid_for_sp'];
}else{
$sponsorid=0;
}
$dateofjoining=date("Y-m-d");;
$address=$_POST['address'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$state=$_POST['state'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$mobileno=$_POST['mobileno'];
$countrycode=$_POST['countrycode'];
$dateofbirth=$_POST['dateofbirth'];
$emailid=$_POST['emailid'];
$myid=$_SESSION['memberid'];

$query = "UPDATE personal SET membername='$membername',
sponsorid='$sponsorid', 
dateofjoining='$dateofjoining',
address='$address', 
city='$city',
state='$state',
country='$country',
mobileno='$mobileno',
countrycode='$countrycode',
dateofbirth='$dateofbirth', emailid='$emailid' WHERE membername='$membername'";

echo $query;
$checkresult = mysql_query($query); 
if ($checkresult) echo 'update query succeeded'; 
else echo 'update query failed';

mysql_close();

//return $frmdetail.php;
?>
```

Please help, I really need this corrected...I'm having headaches with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Did you check if you actually have a member with that name? `WHERE membername='$membername'` ?

Comment: Do you have an existing row with membername='test this'? If there is none, there is no corresponding row for MySQL to update to.

Comment: If running the same query through phpMyAdmin doesn't work, it's because of the query, not the PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the membername to the new value `UPDATE personal SET membername='$membername'` and then using that new value in the WHERE condition. Of course it would return 0 rows as the new value does not exist in the table.

You'll have to use a different field in the WHERE clause (such as id) to update the membername too.

Answer (score 1):

the new value does not exist in the table,but you execute update,so you got this msg: 0 rows affected,

you should be use replace instead of update.

when membername doesn't exist,mysql will call insert ,otherwise mysql will call update.